# Providing Dependabot with a list of dependencies

Tags: package-managers, dependabot, github-dependabot

Is there any way of providing dependabot with a list of dependencies to check? Either by injecting the list or providing a custom [package manager](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.10/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem) for it to use?

Comment: If you have some dependencies only on a private registry, then you can provide a custom config. https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/configuring-access-to-private-registries-for-dependabot

Comment: Yes, but that's not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Github step which allows you to upload an SPDX file to Dependabot: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/spdx-dependency-submission-action

[SPDX](https://spdx.dev/) is an open SBOM format that can be generated by a number of tools.